# Aligning one minipage to other that is stretched

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage

I'm having a problem with the `minipage` option. What I'm trying to do is to align the first `minipage` to the second, since the second is a chemical equation. So here is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{bpchem}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemexec} 
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.25\linewidth}
Oxidation:\\ 
Reduktion: \\
Redoxreaktion:\\
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\linewidth}
$\ce{ \ox{+II}{Mn} \op[2] + 4 \ox{-II}{O} \, \ox{+I}{H} \om[] -> \ox{+VI}{Mn} \, \ox{-II}>{O}_{2(s)} + 2 \ox{+I}{H}_2 \, \ox{-II}{O} + 2 e \om[] }$\\
$\ce{ \ox{+VII}{Mn} \, \ox{-II}{O}_4 \om[] + 2 \ox{+I}{H}_2 \, \ox{-II}{O}  + 3 e \om[] -> 3 \ox{+VI}{Mn} \, \ox{-II}{O}_{2(s)} + 4 OH \om[]}$ \\
$\ce{ \ox{+II}{Mn} \op[2] + 2 \ox{+VII}{Mn} \, \ox{-II}{O}_4 \om[] + 4 \ox{-II}{O} \, \ox{+I}{H} \om[] -> 5 \ox{+VI}{Mn} \, \ox{-II}{O}_{2(s)} + 2 \ox{+I}{H}_2 \, \ox{-II}{O}}$
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably want a `tabular`. However, the example doesn't compile.

Comment: Please fix  your example to have end{document} and to define `\ce`. `! Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \ce `

Comment: Some fixes are good; but none of the commands you use (`\ce`, `\ox`, `\om`) are defined, so it's impossible to work out what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Missing packages were added. Hopefully now will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemexec}
\usepackage{bpchem}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Oxidation: &
  \ce{ \ox{+II}{Mn} \op[2] + 4 \ox{-II}{O} \, \ox{+I}{H} \om[] ->
  \ox{+VI}{Mn} \, \ox{-II}>{O}_{2(s)} + 2 \ox{+I}{H}_2 \, \ox{-II}{O} + 2 e \om[] }
\\[1ex]
Reduktion: &
  \ce{ \ox{+VII}{Mn} \, \ox{-II}{O}_4 \om[] + 2 \ox{+I}{H}_2 \, \ox{-II}{O}  + 3 e \om[] ->
  3 \ox{+VI}{Mn} \, \ox{-II}{O}_{2(s)} + 4 OH \om[]}
\\[1ex]
Redoxreaktion: &
  \ce{ \ox{+II}{Mn} \op[2] + 2 \ox{+VII}{Mn} \, \ox{-II}{O}_4 \om[] + 4 \ox{-II}{O}
    \, \ox{+I}{H} \om[] ->
  5 \ox{+VI}{Mn} \, \ox{-II}{O}_{2(s)} + 2 \ox{+I}{H}_2 \, \ox{-II}{O}}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want that all reactions in your paper are treated equally, define a new environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemexec} 
\usepackage{bpchem}
\usepackage{calc}

\newenvironment{reactionseries}
 {\par % start a new line
  \medskip % but leaving some space
  \noindent % flush left
  \begin{tabular}{
    @{} % no padding at the left
    p{.25\textwidth} % a quarter of the line for the description
    p{.75\textwidth-2\tabcolsep} % the rest for the reaction
    @{} % no padding to the left
  }% here the tabular starts
 }
 {\end{tabular}% here the tabular ends
  \par % new line
  \medskip % leave some space
 }

\begin{document}
\begin{reactionseries}
Oxidation: &
  \ce{ \ox{+II}{Mn} \op[2] + 4 \ox{-II}{O} \, \ox{+I}{H} \om[] -> 
  \ox{+VI}{Mn} \, \ox{-II}>{O}_{2(s)} + 2 \ox{+I}{H}_2 \, \ox{-II}{O} + 2 e \om[] }
\\[1ex]
Reduktion: &
  \ce{ \ox{+VII}{Mn} \, \ox{-II}{O}_4 \om[] + 2 \ox{+I}{H}_2 \, \ox{-II}{O}  + 3 e \om[] ->
  3 \ox{+VI}{Mn} \, \ox{-II}{O}_{2(s)} + 4 OH \om[]}
\\[1ex]
Redoxreaktion: &
  \ce{ \ox{+II}{Mn} \op[2] + 2 \ox{+VII}{Mn} \, \ox{-II}{O}_4 \om[] + 4 \ox{-II}{O} 
    \, \ox{+I}{H} \om[] ->
  5 \ox{+VI}{Mn} \, \ox{-II}{O}_{2(s)} + 2 \ox{+I}{H}_2 \, \ox{-II}{O}}
\end{reactionseries}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you! really helpful

I have but a single question - what does [1ex] stand for? (perhaps a stupid one, but i havent't used it till now)

Comment: @Biri `ex` is a font dependent unit of measure traditionally the height of a lowercase `x`, so egreg was just opening up your linespacing a little bit.`\\[1ex]` adds 1ex to the default spacing between the table rows. using `ex` rather than `pt` or `cm` means that it adapts if the table is set with `\footnotesize` for example.